# What is the purpose of this PCB?

Tags: motor, motor-controller, motordriver

I have a solar screen in my motor home that is motorized with a DC motor (24V.) Today, I tried to move it but no response. I removed all the solar screen and inspected the motor. I saw it has a PCB and on it, something burned. I know it's a capacitor from the shape before I removed it. I removed the dirt, safe the pin and try to operate my screen, but the relay only switched "On/Off" quickly.

Can you help to understand the use of this PCB and if I can use my motor without it?

The burned capacitor is C5 on the schematic of the PCB I've produced. I don't know which type of capacitor it is.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Improved size schematic:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that this circuit is some sort of sensor to detect when the motor has reached the end of its travel and shut it off at that point.

Comment: Thank you jwh20 for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems quite a complex circuit for what it does but in essence it runs the motor measuring the drop on the filter inductor, when the current is too high it drops the relay and stop the motor. C1 and C2 gives a delay for the intervention. For how is structured I'd think that the circuit is actually designed to be powered in both polarities (forward and reverse), so a couple of transistor works in forward and the other one works in reverse, and the diodes exclude the other pair. The C1-C2 back-to-back connection show that's designed to work with a negative supply. Is that the way is connected upstream?

As for the burned capacitor, it's only purpose seems to filter the incoming supply. It should be a (quite big) non-polarized electrolytic capacitor or a huge film capacitor. If the sticking wires are from it, I'd say a big film one. The value shouldn't be critical, the bigger the better.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, it's hard to me to understand some of functionnality of Electronic Components. For the Main functionnality i understood it's to stop the Motor at the end of travel. Now my Problem is, it doesnt run in any way (up or down), maybe the reductor is faulty and the Motor reach an high current too quickly. For the connection, by default-> no voltage or current, if i push "up Button" i've an polarity (orange +, Black-) and it's the opposit if i press "down" Button.

Comment: OK, quick way to check: do not use the circuit and simply apply power to the motor in both direction. If it doesn't move and current is high even switching polarity, you are right, there's some mechanically stuck and the motor is suffering

Comment: That's what i've tryed, the motor work when he is alone and the pcb work when he is alone too... I don't why the PCB detect an overcurent, the motor drain only 250mA...

Whatever, the solar screen work now !